# Can't pass variable from theme hook or controller to custom template

Tags: theming, 8

On Drupal 8, I want pass a variable to a overrides template from my controller OR from the hook theme. 
I do several tries :

from my .module file :

```
function ms_story_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['page__ms_story__global'] = array(
    'variables' => [
      'toto' => "toto", //try one
    ],
    'base hook' => 'page',
    'render element' => 'elements',
    '#tata' => 'tata', //try two
  );
  return $theme;
}
```

from my .php controller file :

```
class customController extends ControllerBase {
  public function map_global($name) {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#theme' => 'page__ms_story__global',
      '#markup' => $this->t("Implement method: hello with parameter(s): $name"),
      '#tutu' => "tutu", //try three
      'variables' => [
        "tyty" => "tyty", //try four
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

But when I want display all available variable from my overrided template file (via {{ kint() }} ), I don't see anywhere variables I want add. Variables 'toto' 'tata' tutu' and 'tyty' aren't present in the array structure displayed via kint (I cleared all cache of course)

Where is my mystake ?

Bonus question : how can I add a variable who use not any cache ? (the variable is calculated again every time the user load page ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use #markup and #theme in the same element. #markup will always take precedence, and #theme is ignored. If you want to output some markup, you need to include that as part of your theme. If the markup is dynamic, then include it as a variable to be passed to your theme (though you need to name the variable as something other than markup).

You've also defined the variable as `toto` in your `hook_theme()` implementation, then passed the value in `#tutu` in your render array. You need to use `'#toto' => 'some value'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help =) I tried with the '#markup'  commented , I tried also with the line '#type' commented but the custom variable doesn't appears in the {{ kint() }} array :/

Comment: Because in your hook_theme, you defined the variable as toto, and in your theme implementation you've defined it as #tutu. These need to match. You need to use `#toto => 'some value'`.

Comment: @Jaypan The last comment you wrote should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each information array must contain either a 'variables' element (for using a #theme element) or a 'render element' element (for render elements), but not both.

Ref: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x